# Lowercase dictionary items within a list python

Tags: python, dictionary, lowercase

I am trying to lowercase all the keys in a dictionary(s) that are within a list. I actually have a code that prints the lowercase output I want within a for loop. I'm using a dictionary comprehension to lowercase, but I'm not sure how to append the changed values to my list.

```
amdardict = [{'1031': 98, '1032': 1, '33007': 70, 'AIRCRAFT_FLIGHT_NUMBER': 'CNFNXQ', 'DAY': 5, 'HEIGHT_OR_ALTITUDE': 1490.0, 'HOUR': 0, 'LATITUDE': 39.71, 'LONGITUDE': -41.79, 'MINUTE': 0, 'MONTH': 10, 'PHASE_OF_AIRCRAFT_FLIGHT': 5, 'TEMPERATURE_DRY_BULB_TEMPERATURE': 289.0, 'WIND_DIRECTION': 219, 'WIND_SPEED': 3.0, 'YEAR': 2019}
{'12101': 248.75, '4006': 55, '7010': 6135, '8009': 3, 'aircraft_flight_number': '????????', 'aircraft_registration_number_or_other_identification': 'AU0155', 'aircraft_tail_number': '??????', 'day': 5, 'destination_airport': '???', 'hour': 0, 'latitude': -34.3166, 'longitude': 151.9333, 'minute': 8, 'month': 10, 'observation_sequence_number': 64, 'origination_airport': '???', 'wind_direction': 208, 'wind_speed': 23.0, 'year': 2019}
]

for d in amdardict: print(dict((k.lower(), v) for k, v in d.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why modify the original list? Can you create a new empty list and slightly modify your code to append to that new list instead of printing:

```
new_list = []
for d in amdardict: 
    new_list.append(dict((k.lower(), v)     for k, v in d.items()))
```

Comment: Thanks J.Behnken, not sure why I didn't think of that. Thank you for the correct answer, will upvote once I have 15 rep points!

Answer (score 0):

To change the keys in-place, you can use the [dict.pop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) method.

```
>>> # Copy the list in case we make a mistake
>>> import copy
>>> backup = copy.deepcopy(amdardict)
>>> for d in amdardict:
...     # <ake a list of keys() because we can't loop over keys()
...     # and change keys simultaneously
...     for k in list(d.keys()):
...         if not k.islower():
                # pop removes the key from the dict and returns the value
...             d[k.lower()] = d.pop(k) 
... 
>>> amdardict
[{'aircraft_flight_number': 'CNFNXQ', 'day': 5, 'height_or_altitude': 1490.0, 'temperature_dry_bulb_temperature': 289.0, 'wind_direction': 219, 'wind_speed': 3.0, 'year': 2019, 'hour': 0, 'latitude': 39.71, 'longitude': -41.79, 'minute': 0, 'month': 10, 'phase_of_aircraft_flight': 5, '1031': 98, '1032': 1, '33007': 70}, {'aircraft_flight_number': '????????', 'aircraft_registration_number_or_other_identification': 'AU0155', 'aircraft_tail_number': '??????', 'day': 5, 'destination_airport': '???', 'hour': 0, 'latitude': -34.3166, 'longitude': 151.9333, 'minute': 8, 'month': 10, 'observation_sequence_number': 64, 'origination_airport': '???', 'wind_direction': 208, 'wind_speed': 23.0, 'year': 2019, '12101': 248.75, '4006': 55, '7010': 6135, '8009': 3}]
```